# Left outer join in access?

Tags: ms-access

Following query does not work in access.

```
SELECT Fields.FieldId, PrecisionSettings.DecimalPlaces 

    from Fields left outer join FieldGroup on Fields.FieldGroupId = FieldGroup.FieldGroupId

    left outer join Category on FieldGroup.CategoryId = Category.CategoryId

    left outer join PrecisionSettings on 

    Category.InputAttributesID=PrecisionSettings.AttributesID
```

It gives error as missing operator in query expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Access you can only join two results at a time. To join more tables you need more parentheses:

```
SELECT
    Fields.FieldId,
    PrecisionSettings.DecimalPlaces 
FROM
(
    (
        Fields
        LEFT OUTER JOIN FieldGroup ON Fields.FieldGroupId = FieldGroup.FieldGroupId
    )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Category ON FieldGroup.CategoryId = Category.CategoryId
)
LEFT OUTER JOIN PrecisionSettings ON Category.InputAttributesID = PrecisionSettings.AttributesID
```